# svnsync with source repository password

Tags: svnsync

The source repository (UTILITIES) has `anon-access = none` specified requiring a password to access it. A user has been setup `svnsync = sourcepass` to use for syncing.

But how to I tell `svnsync` the username and password?

```
SYNCUSER=svnsync
SRCPASS=sourcepass
DESTPASS=destpass
svnsync init --non-interactive \
  --sync-username $SYNCUSER --sync-password $DESTPASS \
  --no-auth-cache \
  "file://path/to/UTILITIES" "svn://svn.company.com/UTILITIES"
```

If I run without `--non-interactive`, it will prompt me to login to the source repository.

*Note: the reason for `--non-interactive` is because initialisation of the mirror is handled by a daemon.*

See: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.c.init.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to pre-cache authentication, which is what I am currently doing.

```
$ svn info svn://svn.company.com/UTILITIES
Username: svnsync
Password: sourcepass
Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? yes
```

`svnsync` can then access the repository in `--non-interactive` mode.